# Eventmachine gem -> block in spawn_threadpool

Tags: ruby, rubygems, eventmachine, tweets, amazon-dynamodb

Followed this tutorial (http://arfon.org/twitter-streaming-with-eventmachine-and-dynamodb) in an attempt to spin up an Amazon listening env.; receives specific tweets and adds them to a dynamo db (via a new thread). Everything works fine however when using eventmachine to spawn the threads I get the following:

```
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'tweetstream'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY = 'HERE IT IS'
AWS_SECRET_KEY = 'YES HERE'


dynamo_db = AWS::DynamoDB.new(:access_key_id => AWS_ACCESS_KEY, :secret_access_key => AWS_SECRET_KEY)

table = dynamo_db.tables['tweets']
table.load_schema

TweetStream.configure do |config|
  config.username = 'geezlouis'
  config.password = 'password'
  config.auth_method = :basic
end

EM.run{
  client = TweetStream::Client.new

  def write_to_dynamo(status)
    EM.defer do
      tweet_hash = {:user_id => status.user.id, 
                    :created_at => status.created_at,
                    :id => status.id,
                    :screen_name => status.user.screen_name}

      begin
        table.items.create(tweet_hash)
      rescue Exception => e  
        puts e.message  
        puts e.backtrace.inspect
      end
    end
  end

  client.track("Romney", "Gingrich") do |status|
    write_to_dynamo(status)
  end  
}
```

> undefined local variable or method `table' for main:Object
>
> ```
> ["tweets.rb:31:in `block in write_to_dynamo'", "/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:1060:in
> ```
>
> `call'",
>   "/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:1060:in`
>   block in spawn_threadpool'"]

Answer (score 0):

table is a local variable, so you're not going to be able to reach it from the method scope.

You want the following:

```
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'tweetstream'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY = 'HERE IT IS'
AWS_SECRET_KEY = 'YES HERE'


dynamo_db = AWS::DynamoDB.new(:access_key_id => AWS_ACCESS_KEY, :secret_access_key => AWS_SECRET_KEY)

table = dynamo_db.tables['tweets']
table.load_schema

TweetStream.configure do |config|
  config.username = 'geezlouis'
  config.password = 'password'
  config.auth_method = :basic
end

EM.run{
  client = TweetStream::Client.new

  def write_to_dynamo(status, table)
    EM.defer do
      tweet_hash = {:user_id => status.user.id, 
                    :created_at => status.created_at,
                    :id => status.id,
                    :screen_name => status.user.screen_name}

      begin
        table.items.create(tweet_hash)
      rescue Exception => e  
        puts e.message  
        puts e.backtrace.inspect
      end
    end
  end

  client.track("Romney", "Gingrich") do |status|
    write_to_dynamo(status, table)
  end  
}
```

You'll also likely want to stop catching "Exception" and instead catch "StandardError", otherwise you won't be able to for example CTRL+C the program.

Comment: I think I'm missing something -> looks like an exact paste of what I submitted.